# Getting data flow algorithm error on EditText visibility

Tags: android, android-edittext, visibility, buttonclick

I have a couple of sets of EditText that i set to visible on a button click. In on my onClick, it is saying that my method is too complex to analyze by data flow algorithm. The code works fine when I run it. How can I remove this error? Or should i just ignore it since the the code is working fine?  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
public void showEditText(){ //method is too complex to analyze by data algorithm

    if(!et1.isShown() && !et2.isShown()){
        et1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        et2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else if(!et2.isShown() && !et3.isShown()){
        et2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        et3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else if(!et4.isShown() && !et5.isShown()){
        et4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        et5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else if(!et6.isShown() && !et7.isShown()){
        et6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        et7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else if(!et8.isShown() && !et9.isShown()){
        et8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        et9.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else if(!et10.isShown() && !et11.isShown()){
        et10.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        et11.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else if(!et12.isShown() && !et13.isShown()){
        et12.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        et13.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else if(!et14.isShown() && !et15.isShown()){
        et14.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       et15.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?
What function should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because your code is too complex for IntelliJ's data flow algorithm. Instead of all the if else statements a more cleaner approach and ideally what you may want to do is pass the edittexts you want to show as arguments to the method:

```
public void showEditText(EditText et1, EditText et2) {
   if(!et1.isShown() && !et2.isShown()){
        et1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        et2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this and it still gives me the warning. Since the code is working fine, should I worry about the data flow algorithm warning?

Comment: Can you post some more code on what you are trying to achieve, and where you are calling this method from?

Comment: Actually I fixed it. Instead of using the if/else statement, I used Booleans to check if the previous EditText isShown then make the next one visible. Thanks for the input.